# How to edit the metadata of a song from iPod music library in ios

Tags: iphone

I want to edit the metadata of a song that exists in the iPod library, is this possible with ios?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the use of a Public API (ie., an app that includes this functionality would be rejected by Apple for public distribution).

So yes, it's possible- but it'd be more of a "hack" than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

However, the rating is part of metadata and it can be edited.

```
var r:Int
var song = MPMusicPlayerController().nowPlayingItem
song?.setValue(r, forKey: "rating")
```

So... is there any similar option for genre? The following does not work

```
 var song = MPMusicPlayerController().nowPlayingItem
 song?.setValue(r, forKey: "genre")
```